# Writing partition for quicksort in scheme

Tags: scheme, quicksort

I am having a lot of trouble with writing scheme...

I am trying to write quicksort using scheme.  I have seen tons of answers but they don't really make any sense to me and this is mostly because I barely understand functional programming at all.

I have defined my pivot like this:

```
(define (pivot lis)
  (car lis))
```

That works fine (and is easy to write..)

For my understanding of the partition function, you have the original list and then you split it into 2 new lists, one that contains values larger than the pivot, and one that contains values smaller or equal to the pivot.

This is how I've tried to implement it:

```
(define (partition lis)
  (if (null? lis) '())
  (else (lambda (lis1 lis2)
          (if (< (car lis) pivot) append lis1)
          (partition (append lis2)))))
```

This is the error I'm getting: 
. else: not allowed as an expression in: (else (lambda (lis1 lis2) (if (< (car lis) pivot) append lis1) (partition (append lis2))))

I am not really sure how to do this, any ideas on how I can make this work?  Or is my reasoning off?

Comment: as the error says: `else` can't be used on its own, it must start the last clause of a `cond` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (partition ls)
  (partition-aux ls (pivot ls) '() '()))

(define (parition-aux ls pivot smaller larger)
  (cond
    ((empty? ls) (list smaller larger))
    ((< (car ls) pivot)
     (parition-aux (cdr ls) pivot (cons (car ls) smaller) larger))
    (else
     (partition-aux (cdr ls) pivot smaller (cons (car ls) larger)))))
```

you need to define another function to do the job. because you need 2 more arguments to hold the list of smaller and larger numbers. This is one way of doing it. there are other ways that are shorter to type. but I wanted to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you!  I really just thought I could do it all inside a lambda.  Also, clearly my basic understanding of scheme is way off and needs more practice.  Thank you for taking the time to show me.

Comment: It is possible to make recursive procedures using lambdas. But its hard to understand. The most common way of defining an auxiliary function is with a named let. You can read about it. I just thought a separate function would be clearer.

Comment: You can also use internal definitions to define your helper function. For beginners, that's what I usually suggest. Of course, like you said, seasoned Schemers prefer named `let` instead.